# Correct way to copy _bstr_t to wchar_t*

Tags: c++

There is a class A that derives from _bstr_t. It needs to have a method that takes a wchar_t* and copies the bstr into it. Is this the safest way to do it if wcsncpy_s understands bstrs?

```
class A: public _bstr_t
{
    ----
    ----

    void CopyTo(wchar_t* buf, size_t destinationsize)
    {  
        wcsncpy_s(buf, destinationsize, *this, length());
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
void CopyTo(wchar_t* buf, size_t destinationsize) const
{  
   wcsncpy_s(buf, destinationsize, static_cast<wchar_t const *>(this), _TRUNCATE);
}
```

If you don't use _TRUNCATE, then the invalid parameter handler will be invoked when the buffer is too small to contain the entire string (plus null):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ksazx244%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: i am ok with the invalid parameter handler which will set the destination to 0. I am more interested to know the casting part. why do you need to cast?

Comment: @Sriram: You need to cast because just dereferencing "this" simply gives you a reference to the `A` object, and not a pointer to the `wchar_t` string, which is stored in a separate object altogether.  The cast invokes `_bstr_t`'s `wchar_t *` operator function, which returns the `wchar_t *` stored in the actual storage object.  Also, if the `_bstr_t` was initialized with a `char *`, the function will perform the `wchar_t` conversion and store the result before returning the pointer.

Comment: i am actually passing *this and by default will point to the first member of _bstr_t which is the actual string

Comment: @Sriram: What you are doing is not at all safe. Have a gander at comutil.h, and you will see that `_bstr_t` isn't laid out the way you appear to think it is.  The strings are stored in a `Data_t` object which is pointed to by the `m_Data` member.  Yes, it just so happens that the `wchar_t*` member happens to come first in the `Data_t` object, but you're depending on very fragile and coincidental internals of these classes.  You also don't get the automatic conversion behavior.  _bstr_t is *not meant to be accessed* in this way.  You should really use the cast.

Comment: i agree. dont you need static_cast<wchar_t const* const>(this) ?

Comment: also your this needs to be *this or else it will not invoke the wchat_t operator.

Comment: @Sriram: Deepest apologies; I just realized that your use of *thisis actually fine, because the cast operator gets called implicitly due to the type expected by the function.  So go ahead with *this.  Again, sorry for both my haste and my dimwittedness.

Comment: -1 for misinformation and an example that won't even compile. What Sriram does is just fine. Have a look at `comutil.h` yourself, and you will see that _bstr_t has an `operator const wchar_t*()` which handles the conversion. And you cannot convert `this` (which is a `_bstr_t*` rvalue) to `const wchar_t*`.

Comment: @pgroke: Yes, on reflection I deserve it.  Apologies to all.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is just fine. `wcsncpy_s` does not "understand" `_bstr_t`s. It does however "understand" a `wchar_t const*`, and `_bstr_t` has suitable conversion operators:

```
class _bstr_t {
public:
// ...
    // Extractors
    //
    operator const wchar_t*() const throw();
    operator wchar_t*() const throw();
    operator const char*() const ;
    operator char*() const ;
```

---

Be vigilant not to do this with any varargs functions though (e.g. `printf`, `CString::Format`). If you still do, MSVC will happily push the whole `_bstr_t` object onto the stack without a warning. And since `_bstr_t` does *not* have a suitable layout to be "interpreted" as a pointer, it will *not* work.
(Yes, the first and only member is a pointer. But it's not a pointer to a string, it's a pointer to a struct that's first member is a pointer to a string.)

The same thing *does* work with `CString` however, because `CString` was specifically designed to allow that nasty trick. Which isn't saying I would recomment doing it.